# Kafka-Spark Streaming Distributed The group coordinate is not available (Host2:9092(id:2147483645))

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I want use kafka-sparkstreaming to process data(maven: spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11). Spark Streaming consumes streaming from Kafka. And I have already finish a producer with springboot. But when I try to run my kafka-sparkstreaming code, it keep return like this:

```
24/03/01 13:42:39 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Discovered group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
24/03/01 13:42:39 INFO ConsumerCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Revoking previously assigned partitions []
24/03/01 13:42:39 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] (Re-)joining group
24/03/01 13:42:39 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
24/03/01 13:42:39 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Discovered group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
24/03/01 13:42:39 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Discovered group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] (Re-)joining group
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Discovered group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Discovered group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null)
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] (Re-)joining group
24/03/01 13:42:40 INFO AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=spark-streaming-application] Group coordinator Host2:9092 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) is unavailable or invalid, will attempt rediscovery
```

My env:
I use three virtual machines in VM. IPs set as [Host0, Host1, Host2]
OS: all of them is Ubuntu 22.04.
Code: Java 8, maven project
Kafka: 2.0.0 with scale 2.11, both Server and Client
Zookeeper: 3.4.12
Spark: 2.4.0
Work topic: test-topic

The kafka-topic.sh return like this:

```
root@ProjectTest:/opt/kafka_2.11-2.0.0# bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper Host1:2181,Host0:2181,Host2:2181/kafka --describe
Topic:__consumer_offsets        PartitionCount:50       ReplicationFactor:1     Configs:segment.bytes=104857600,cleanup.policy=compact,compression.type=producer
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 5    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 6    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 8    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 9    Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 10   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 11   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 12   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 13   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 14   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 15   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 16   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 17   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 18   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 19   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 20   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 21   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 22   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 23   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 24   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 25   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 26   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 27   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 28   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 29   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 30   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 31   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 32   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 33   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 34   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 35   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 36   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 37   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 38   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 39   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 40   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 41   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 42   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 43   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 44   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 45   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 46   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 47   Leader: 2       Replicas: 2     Isr: 2
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 0       Replicas: 0     Isr: 0
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1     Isr: 1
Topic:test-topic        PartitionCount:4        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:
        Topic: test-topic       Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,1,0 Isr: 2,0
        Topic: test-topic       Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 0,2,1 Isr: 1,0,2
        Topic: test-topic       Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,0,2 Isr: 1,0,2
        Topic: test-topic       Partition: 3    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,0,1 Isr: 2,0
```

And my Client properties:

```
# kafka conf
kafka.bootstrap.servers=Host0:9092,Host1:9092,Host2:9092
kafka.topic.name=test-topic
kafka.group.id=spark-streaming-application
kafka.key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
kafka.value.deserializer=org.groupm.sparkstreaming.deserialize.JSONDeserializer
kafka.auto.offset.reset=latest
kafka.enable.auto.commit=false

# spark streaming conf
spark.app.name=SparkStreaming-Kafka-Application
spark.master=spark://Host0:7077
# No hadoop, Standalone model
spark.streaming.batch.duration=500
spark.streaming.checkpoint.dir=file:///opt/tmp/spark/checkpoint
```

My code with kafka:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf()
                    .setAppName(appConfig.getProperty("spark.app.name"))
                    .setMaster(appConfig.getProperty("spark.master"));

            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

            JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations
                    .milliseconds( Long.parseLong(appConfig.getProperty("spark.streaming.batch.duration")) ));
            ssc.checkpoint(appConfig.getProperty("spark.streaming.checkpoint.dir"));

            Collection<String> topics = Arrays.asList(appConfig.getProperty("kafka.topic.name"));

            JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, String>> stream =
                    KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(
                            ssc,
                            LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent(),
                            ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe(topics, kafkaConfig)
                    );
```

It use Dstream.

I try to connect Host2:9092 and it works. Then I look up `$KAFKA_HOME/logs/server.log` but there have no log message about Coordinator.

I clean the `/tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer*` and restart server and client, but problem still here.

I tried delete topic `__consumer_offsets`，which I found in other qusetion post, but Kafka refused to delete it.

The most puzzling thing is that I try to find is there any problems with my kafka, so I write a new programme. It is a simple consumer and it have same config with my kafka-sparkstreaming app. I run the new programme at the same computer, same environment. And the new programme receive the message successfully. (I don't know if the reason is difference of `KafkaUtils` and `KafkaConsumer`).

So now I really don't know where is wrong, what is the root problem and how to solve it.